# Reading nested JSON into Spring config bean from K8S ConfigMap File

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, config

We have a enterprise Kubernetes setup on which I am deploying a spring boot application

The service injects configMap as a json file at the location - `/etc/config/appConfig.json`

The JSON File looks like

```
{
    "configResolution": {
      "resolved": {
        "groupid": "listener-consumerGrp",
        "topic": "Product"
      }
    }
 }
```

I am trying to read the K-V pairs to variables in spring boot

```
String groupid;
String topic
```

Need assistance on how to read using Spring Cloud Kubernetes, with refresh of 15 min

Here is the application.yml , I used

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      config:
        name: PLACEHOLDER-LISTENER
        namespace: team924
        enable-api: false
        paths:
          -/etc/config/appConfig.json
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: polling
        period: 150000
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: could you share your bean configuration code? How are you accessing them Your beans have to be annotated with the `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@RefreshScope` to reload them automatically after the configured period.

Comment: Have you tried to move your configuration from application.yml to bootstrap.yml ? Some properties must be in bootstrap.yml because it's loaded before application.yml